# Python function to write a CSV

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

```
def write_csv(mydf):
    nominal = mydf.name 
    csvname = nominal + ".csv"
    mydf.to_csv( csvname , encoding='utf-8', header='False')
```

This didn't work, when I called the function:

```
write_csv(ulangp) 
Attribute Error:  'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'
```

What is the right way to do this in a function assuming I want to pass in a dataframe?

Comment: What did you expect `name` to give you?

Comment: I had seen some other article where it was posited .name would yield the literal (string)  name of the dataframe, which is what i want.

Comment: The data frame has no intrinsic name. You can assign one if you want: `ulangp.name = "foo"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a[n optional] `name` parameter that is used if the dataframe does not have a preset name:

```
def write_csv(mydf, name="default"): # Use any good default name here
    try:
        nominal = mydf.name 
    except AttributeError:
        nominal = name
    csvname = nominal + ".csv"
    mydf.to_csv( csvname , encoding='utf-8', header='False')
```

Comment: Interesting.   I was expecting some low-level technique to be able to turn the object into a string variable for the purpose of the function.   Requiring users in the main program to assign a name just before they call the function won't work.  The purpose was to write a csv file out that has a unique name, i.e. the string representation of the dataframe's variable.  If a bunch of people called the function as per above, it would keep overwriting default.csv because nobody will set the .name attribute first.

Comment: The same will happen if one program saves two dataframes with the same name. (Dataframe names do not have to be unique.)

Comment: The situation is that there is a main program and in this program, about 10 dataframes are created via canned logic, each with its own name.  I wanted a utility function to allow the user to pass in each one in turn and write out a CSV.  I did not anticipate they'd have to set a ".name" attribute.  I thought I could query some (low-level) directory attribute to get it.